# Why spring cloud getting started sections provide not working examples of pom.xml?

Tags: spring-cloud

I would like to ask experienced developers a stupid question regarding Spring Cloud documentation. Why is it so misleading, for example, let's start just a new project

1. go to [spring-cloud-config website](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)
2. include their `<dependencyManagement>` section (suggested part of pom) into your fresh pom.xml
3. notice compile errors, e.g `@EnableConfigServer` is not found

what you really want is:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

So my question is how I supposed to know how to build the correct pom.xml reading that docs? Have I missed something and `spring-cloud-config-server` dependency is mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you miss the last past of the instruction. They stated very clear that

> To run your own server use the spring-cloud-config-server dependency and @EnableConfigServer

That means you need to change the default spring-cloud-starter-config to spring-cloud-config-server dependency in your pom file.